# NFC_Reader_Xamarin_VS2022

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xaml, nfc

Hello (I'm not very good at English, so I'll be using google translate), I'm creating an Android app using Xamarin Forms and my IDE is Visual Studio 2022, I've been having difficulties reading some recorded tags that I have with me, because even though my app can communicate using NFC (cell phone vibrates and emits sound effect with the approach),   The field that should receive the value of the tag remains unchanged. I used chatgpt a lot because it was of great help for resolving doubts, but everything has a limit, as it really couldn't give me an idea of what was going on so there wasn't any kind of information being read

Don't notice the term 'Scan_NFC' because my purpose is to implement this code to another application with a qrcode scanner.

In the AndroidManifest.xml property, I left the permissions 'ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE', 'BIND_NFC_SERVICE', 'NFC', 'NFC_PREFERRED_PAYMENT-INFO' and 'NFC_TRANSACTION_EVENT' checked

Main.Page.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Scan_NFC.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="NFC TAGS" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Entry x:Name="meuEntry" Text="Tag NFC não lida ainda." HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Main.Page.xaml.cs

```
using Plugin.NFC;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Scan_NFC
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Atribui o Entry com o nome 'meuEntry' à variável no código-behind
            meuEntry = (Entry)FindByName("meuEntry");

            // Inicializa o NFC e registra o evento OnMessageReceived
            CrossNFC.Current.OnMessageReceived += NfcMessageReceived;
        }

        private void NfcMessageReceived(ITagInfo tagInfo)
        {
            var idBytes = tagInfo.Identifier;
            var message = BitConverter.ToString(idBytes);

            // Atualiza o Entry com o valor da tag NFC
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                meuEntry.Text = $"Tag NFC Lida - ID: {message}";
                // Exibe um alerta opcional
                DisplayAlert("Tag NFC Lida", $"ID: {message}", "OK");
            });
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MainPage OnAppearing");

            CrossNFC.Current.StartListening();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MainPage OnDisappearing");

            CrossNFC.Current.StopListening();
        }
    }
}
```

Main.Activity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.NFC;

namespace Scan_NFC.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Scan_NFC", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            CrossNFC.Init(this);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# and Xamarin, but there is not a common "NFC tag". There are a lot of tag types around (e.g. Credit/Payment cards, simple storage cards, hotel room access cards) and each of them needs a different (technical) class to work with. You need to know what kind of NFC tags you wan't to work with, grab the data sheets and find out what ommands are necessary to "open" (read) them. Good luck !

Comment: Yes, I've made some modifications to the program already, where now it's able to recognize the content of the tags, but thank you for the advice Michael, it's an aspect that I still have to implement.